# Is it possible to do Model.first without conditions

Tags: mongoid

I wanted to ask if I want to get the first row in a table in mongoid, is it possible to write Model.first? without entering any conditions? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `Model.first` works as expected in Mongoid.

Just a quick example from an application I had running:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.1.0)
1.9.2p290 :001 > Hotel.first
 => #<Hotel _id: 4e94e8ab7d1645d6be00003c, _type: nil, created_at: 2011-10-12 01:08:59 UTC, updated_at: 2011-12-01 00:40:59 UTC, deleted_at: nil, name: "A hotel", code: "0545">
```

Comment: No problems Dalia - if you're happy with this response, please 'accept' the answer so the question is marked as answered. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,  `User.first`  will definitely work.
For meore options in querying you can refer [documentation here](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/querying.html#queries)